# деление на ноль проверка через isFinite

Tags: javascript, html, css

как через isFinite проверить деление на ноль?

```
    <input type="button" value=" &#215; " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '*';checkLength(this);"


function div(value) 
    {
        calculator.answer.value += '/';

        if (!isFinite(calculator.answer.value))
        {
            alert("Divide by zero error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Не до конца ясен и понятен ваш код.

Comment: функцию написал но что то не хватает,или я не так понял работу isFinite

Comment: В вашем коде вы проверяете какую-то строку. А не результат операции. Сделайте для отладки `alert(calculator.answer.value)` перед проверкой и посмотрите что у вас уходит в функцию isFinite

Comment: понял в чем проблема,мне тогда нужно достать регулярными выражениями все кроме "/" и проверить на ноль?

Comment: Регулярные выражения здесь это из пушки по воробьям. Не до конца понимаю вашу основную задачу, но как мне кажется лучше вам поменять всю концепцию вашего скрипта..

Comment: Изначально, тест isFinite чихать хотел на ноль. Его задача ответить, является ли число конечным, или бесконечным.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = 10/0;
alert(isFinite(result));
```

Выводит **false**

```
var result = 10/2;
alert(isFinite(result));
```

Выводит **true**